# Getting the memory address of all Objects at runtime in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Is it possible to get Objects' memory address at runtime?

For a certain c++ project, is it possible  to track all objects' information, including memory address at runtime, lifetime and the counts of load & store?

Comment: In C++ the pointer to the object is a memory location. The other information you are looking for requires some kind of instrumentation. Are these statistics something you want for profiling or would they continue to be used in production?

Comment: In fact, i just want to analyse all the objects' information in some certain benchmark, such as SPEC cpu 2006 & Parsec.