# How to track information of all objects in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a c++ project of the following piece of code:

```
class A {..}
class B {..}
cLaas C { .. B b;..}
operations for A a, B b , C c ..
```

Now, i want to get **memory address**, **lifetime** & **the counts of loads/stores** of these objects.

So, in LLVM. How can i get these information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the memory address of all Objects at runtime in LLVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527218/getting-the-memory-address-of-all-objects-at-runtime-in-llvm)

Comment: It's not a reasonable thing to do on LLVM level, with all the types stripped off. Far better to instrument the code with Clang, where you still have all the C++ type information.

Comment: Can you make it clear?  I haven't a good konwledge of Clang. Do you mean using Clang to modify the source code?